# Set Image Path from outside drive from our application's root directory

Tags: asp.net

I am using ASP  image control for image display or HTML image control for that, I want to set the image URL of image that is outside of our web application's root directory...
On Which way this is Possible???

Comment: what did you try? you should be able to set an absolute path starting with http://... did you try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Response.WriteFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8k0d9b3e.aspx) to serve the image file from a custom handler.

```
Response.ContentType = "image/jpg";
Response.WriteFile(@"c:\images\myimage.jpg")
Response.End();
```

Alternatively you can also achieve this using a custom [VirtualPathProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.hosting.virtualpathprovider.aspx). This allows you you remap specific paths to alternative streams, whether it's the database or another location.

If your application is a child application in IIS, and you actually just want to reference a parent image, just use a slash to get back to the root, `/myimage.jpg`, or an absolute path to reference a different application `http://www.myotherapp.com/myimage.jpg`.

Comment: And also you can create a virtual path on the IIS.